# Jasper report unicode font not showing in PDF

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am using jasper report with Spring MVC. I have generated font.jar from jaspersoft studio 6.6.0 and add it to my application classpath. I am trying to use vrinda.ttf and sutonnyOMJ.ttf.

While the report is rendered properly in jasper studio, when I am using it from my application no unicode fonts are showing for PDF export. For excel export all values are showing properly but pdf is not working.

Font Family from my custom font.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="vrinda">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/vrinda/vrinda.ttf]]></normal>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">vrinda</export>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">vrinda</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="sutonny">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/sutonny/SutonnyOMJ.ttf]]></normal>
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/sutonny/SutonnyMJ-Bold.ttf]]></bold>
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/sutonny/SutonnyMJ-Italic.ttf]]></italic>
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/sutonny/SutonnyMJ-BoldItalic.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">SutonnyOMJ</export>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">SutonnyOMJ</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="myName" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a43ee182-4df8-4ea4-b26f-b8b21078c9d1">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="dbname"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[Query]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ClientName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ClientName"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="Table"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="20" y="5" width="500" height="30" uuid="f4900f30-da32-4cec-9142-10b111debcf3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Vrinda" size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["\u09AA\u09CD\u09B0\u09A4\u09BF\u09AC\u09C7\u09A6\u09A8"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="82" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="b35f8d0e-5c47-46c7-b71c-c63dd7706724">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9609ebcc-b3ae-4997-92b2-9aa48843434a"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ClientName]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="82" y="64" width="308" height="30" uuid="ba9cab6a-2688-4601-bedb-3b62913a2cfb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9609ebcc-b3ae-4997-92b2-9aa48843434a"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Vrinda" size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ClientName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Java Code:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSourceFile);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, reportRequestDTO.getConnection());
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

ExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(print);
exporter.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

OutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(path);
exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.exportReport();
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Excel Image for header unicode (Which is not showing in PDF)

[image]

Comment: 1) The font defined as `<fontFamily name="vrinda">` at xml. But at *jrxml* you are using `<font fontName="Vrinda" size="26"/>`. Try to use name at lower case as at font definition 2) Try to use another font

Comment: if I use `vrinda`, it raises JRFontNotFoundException. Same case, if I use `Sutonny` the family name it raises error but with `SuttonyOMJ` it works except pdf. I think it might be a problem of jar and application connection.

Comment: Can anyone help that how to add custom font jar in spring mvc project? I have just add it as external library and iml.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am using maven.